# R plotly: How to remove color mapping variable from trace name

Tags: r, plotly

If I map 'color' to a variable which is neither x, y nor name, the color mapping variable gets added to the trace name on hover and in the legend:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5, 50, 1), 
             y = letters[1:5], 
             c = LETTERS[1:5],
             name = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y,
             type = "bar", 
             color = ~c,              
             name = ~name,
             hoverinfo = "x+y+name")
p
```

How can I display only the name without the color mapping variable?

**EDIT**

Below is a more complex example where the color is mapped to a variable that represents a ranking. The 'name' is some arbitrary name that does not have a ranking. The y variable is an ordered factor that needs to be displayed in the given sequence. I only want to display the name, not the ranking variable.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5, 50, 1), 
             y = factor(letters[1:5], 
                        levels = c("a", "e", "c", "d", "b")), 
             c = LETTERS[1:5],
             name = c("qwe", "zxc", "sdf", "bnm", "ert"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y,
             type = "bar", 
             color = ~c,  
             colors = brewer.pal(8, "Blues")[4:8],
             name = ~name,
             hoverinfo = "x+y+name")
p
```

Comment: To remove color variable from legend do `name = ~c`

Comment: Or change: `color = ~name` if you what your legend labels to be "aa", "bb", ....

Comment: Thanks @EnriquePérezHerrero. I noticed my example was too simple for the real life issue I encountered and didn't represent the full problem. I have edited my post with a better, more complex example. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This code sets `color = ~name`

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5, 50, 1), 
                 y = factor(letters[1:5], 
                            levels = c("a", "e", "c", "d", "b")), 
                 c = LETTERS[1:5],
                 name = c("qwe", "zxc", "sdf", "bnm", "ert"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y,
             type = "bar", 
             color = ~name,  
             colors = brewer.pal(8, "Blues")[4:8],
             name = ~name,
             hoverinfo = "x+y+name")
p
```

The plot looks this way:
[image: plotly_example_R]

Comment: Thanks @Enrique, however, I require the color mapped by the particular sequence of variable c.